# Spark to redshift. Flatten array to string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, amazon-redshift, scala-collections

I am trying to save a nested JSON to redshift using the spark-redshift connector

The problem is redshift wont accept the structure of the dataframe because it has an array

So my question is, is there a way to flatten the array of columns foo and bar and convert their values to a string?

here is what I have so far to get the items as an array

```
val basketItems = df.select($"OrderContainer.BasketInfo.BasketId",
  $"OrderContainer.BasketInfo.MenuId",
  explode($"OrderContainer.BasketInfo.Items")).toDF("BasketId","MenuId","Items")
```

and here is the json I am using (formatted for readability):

```
{
   "OrderContainer":{
      "BasketInfo":{
         "BasketId":"kjOIxlJFc0WYdQXm2AXksg",
         "MenuId":119949,
         "Items":[
            {
               "ProductId":12310,
               "UnitPrice":5.5,
               "foo":[1,2,3],
               "bar":["a","b","c"]
            },
            {
               "ProductId":456323,
               "UnitPrice":5.5,
               "foo":[1,2,3],
               "bar":["a","b","c"]
            },
            {
               "ProductId":23432432,
               "UnitPrice":5.5,
               "foo":[1,2,3],
               "bar":["a","b","c"]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: are you really intending to have a field in your Redshift data `Items` that is a comma-delimited jumble of text? if so, you can just flatten an array with some delimiter. Otherwise, you could make a separate table for Items

Comment: Thanks @Kristian thats just the schema of the items, it wont be a jumble of text at all. Thanks for the advice anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI

I have solved it by creating a function to make the array a string.

```
val mkString = udf((a: Seq[Any]) => a.mkString(","))
```

Make sure to import the udf function.

Then all you have to use is the withColumn function.

```
.withColumn("foo", mkString($"foo"))
```